# How do I calculate the size of stack using Lock free algorithm?

Tags: c++, synchronization, locking, compare-and-swap

```
       struct Node {
              Node *next;
              data_t val;
              } *Top;

        data_t pop()
           {
             Node *t, *x;
                do{
                   t=top;
                   if(t==NULL)
                      return EMPTY;
                   x=t->next;
                   } while(!CAS(& Top, t, x));
            return t-val;
            }
```

The above code is an implementation of pop operation. How can I compute the lenght of the stack in lock free (CAS) ?

Comment: CAS tells you if the top element of the stack was unchanged. Simply use it to walk the stack, one element at a time, with each iteration proceeding only if CAS verified that the top of the stack remains unchanged. If you get to the end, you know the length of the stack, otherwise you start over.

Comment: do{
                   t=top;
                   if(t==NULL)
                      return EMPTY;
                   x=t->next;
                   len++

                   } while(!CAS(& Top, t, x));
            return len;
            }

is it ok ?

Comment: CAS is not lock-free. It is essentially a spin-lock.

Comment: ok, but how to find the length using cas